# Cassandra CQL 3 strange behaviour. Error making delete queries

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, cql

Today I decided to use CQL and unfortunately I came accross MANY problems with CQL 3 and Composite column. One of them which I hadn't solve was following:

I have table with 4 composite primary keys. Let's name them c_key0, c_key1, c_key2, c_key3.
I add some data and then I want to remove all row where c_key0='L1' and c_key1='L2', doesn't matter what values are assigned to c_key2 and c_key3. When I made a query "DELETE FROM Composite WHERE c_key0='L1' and c_key1='L2' and get an error.When I made a query c_key0='L1' and c_key1='L2' and c_key2>='' and c_key3>='' and I get an error again. It is really stupid. Where am I wrong ?.

P.S. I'm using JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

CQL is not meant to be a fully general query language, and Cassandra is not meant to be a fully general relational database. CQL may eventually evolve to the point where you can give any SQL-92 query you like and expect results, but it's not there now, and it's not even a design goal.

So, long story short, that's not a supported way of doing range deletion.

Comment: What kind of range deletion are supported ?